# Do i need to synchronize two threads (1 reading, 1 writing) in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

The title is pretty much self-explainatory.

Do i need to synchronize two threads (1 is reading while the other one is writing) in Java?

I'll add more details:

Let's consider we have 3 classes, 1 containing the shared memory, 1 for the writing thread that is going to increment a variable from the shared memory object and 1 for the reading thread that is going to print the value of the variable in the shared object.

Comment: Not much to go on here.

Comment: No, it's not self-explanatory. What are these threads reading and writing? Is the reading and writing mechanism itself thread-safe?

Comment: Not, if the reading thread does not read what the writing thread writes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, Just in your case. If the changing thread starts incrementing, and the reading thread then inspects, it could receive the old value.

That is not a problem if the increment is just that, and not a time consuming operation.

***The most important: atomicity of assignment to memory:***
*The JLS as I remember:* On read, for `int` the bytes also won't be corrupt: a mix of old and new bytes, say from 255 to 256 getting 0x00_00 or 0x01_FF. (Unless on an embedded processor, java me).
This does not hold for `long` or `double`.
For those types one can however use:

```
volatile long counter;
volatile double impreciseCounter;
```

Which guarantees atomicity by taking precautions between threads' execution.

Purely for coding style, on principle, I still would use `AtomicInteger` or at least `volatile`, as such technical implementation requirements seem too compiler and processor dependent. Expected of a monopolistic stake holder.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't really care about getting the "old value", it will get the new one the next iteration. :)